# Derive from a Silverlight Parent Page and extend the Child Page

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight Parent Page which is like a master page.
the child page derives from the parent page.
This works fine.
But if i want to add additional controls on the child page it is not possible.
How can i achieve this functionality in Silverlight? Can anybody suggest some good workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Look for a place in your XAML code when you want to insert the new controls, and in that place put a `<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentTag" />`. In code create a property of type `Object` that sets the Content property of the newly added tag. Now you have a spot in your XAML to put stuff. At the end you might get something like this:

```
<my:SelectorPriorizador>
    <my:SelectorPriorizador.MyFirstContent>
        <Button Content="Copiar Priorizacion"
                        Height="23"
                        Click="btnCopiarPriorizacion_Click" />
    </my:SelectorPriorizador.MyFirstContent>
</my:SelectorPriorizador>
```

your code might look like:

```
public object MyFirstContent
{
    get { return ContentTag.Content; }
    set { ContentTag.Content = value; }
}
```

The beauty of this is that you can add as many ContentPresenters as needed.

Comment: arturo,Thanks for your answer. That helps me a great deal.